# how to find min value in array of very large size and also large values inside array in c

Tags: c

I am trying to find min value of an array then checking min value frequency, but the problem is if size of array and values it stored is large, my code does not work.

**1 < A[i] < 10^9**

**1 < N < 10^5**
**1< T < 10**

here A is array, N is size of array and T is number of test cases

**c program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

**finding min value**

```
int findMin(int A[], int N)
{
    int min;
    int i;
    if(N>2)
    {
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            if( A[i]<=A[i+1])
            {
                min = A[i];
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i]=A[i+1];
                A[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        min = A[0];
    }

    return freq(min,A,N);

}
```

**frequency of minimum value in array**

```
int freq(int min, int A[], int N)
{
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(min == A[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count%2;
}
```

**main()**

```
int main()
{

    int *A,N;
    int i,T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T>0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&N);
        A = (int *)calloc(N,sizeof(int));
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        }
        if(findMin(A,N) == 1)
        {
            printf("Lucky\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unlucky\n");
        }

        T--;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Edit] Coding goal
`count%2` is for checking frequency is odd or even

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: time complexity problem

Comment: Your solution is O(n) and it is optimal. **Update**: No, wait. Your `findMin` is weird. Is it some kind of trimmed bubble-sort? Just keep the `min` value and compare each element to it updating if necessary. Why are you touching the array values at all?

Comment: What was your reasoning for `count%2`?

Comment: count%2 is for checking frequency is odd or even @miket25

Comment: Frequency? Odd or even? What is the meaning of such a measure at all?

Comment: what you mean by keeping min value and compare with each element of array @OldProgrammer

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for arrays of size 2. Also, you are needlessly rearranging array why looking for the minimum element. Also you do not need second sweep, you can calculate frequency on the first one.

Comment: Unless there's something going on after this operation that requires all the data, you don't need an array at all.  You need the current minimum value and the number of times you've seen it.  When you get a new minimum, the count goes to 1; when you see the current minimum again, increment the count.  Keep reading, checking, counting.  Report at the end.

Comment: The findMin function goes out-of-bounds if the last element is the min for certain cases. Perhaps just rewrite it to be a simple loop saving the first index as a min and compare with the rest of the array updating the min along way.

Comment: actually i am printing "Lucky" if frequency is odd else "Unlucky" @EugeneSh.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Given the OP is only interested in the count being odd or even, there is no even need to count. Just flip a coin..err a boolean. Still O(n), though

Comment: @EugeneSh: If the OP only needs the parity on the count, then yes: `parity = 1` when you get a new minimum, thereafter `parity = !parity;`, noting carefully that it is not advisable to use the 'compound assignment operator' version of `!` — using `a != a` is a bad move!

Comment: I can see some `calloc`s but cannot see any `free`s

Comment: since you got sorted array from find min there is no need to check for entire array when min == A[i] is false you can exit from the loop to save further check which is unnecessary, you are concerned only about min val frequency.
` if(min == A[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
else break;`

Comment: @DilipKumar It is not sorted. It is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in finding the minimum value in an array, and you're interested in the "frequency" where you define it as whether the count of the minimum is odd or even, perhaps this is what you need?

```
int findMinAndFreq(int A[], int N){
   if(N == 0){
      printf("Array is empty");
      return 0;
   }
   if(N == 1){
      return 1;
   }

   int min = A[0];
   int count = 1;
   for(int i = 1; i<N; i++){
      if(A[i] == min){
         count++;
      }
      if(A[i] < min){
         min = A[i];
         count = 1;
      }
   }
   return count%2;
}
```

Comment: `if(N == 1){
      return 1;
   }` is unnecessary. `unsigned count;` is also more defensive for _large_ arrays as OF is not an issue - or just use `count ^= 1;` rather than `count++;`.  `if(N <= 0){` may be a more defensive first test.  Yet good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if( A[i]<=A[i+1])
        {
        ...
```

On the last iteration of the loop when `i` is `N-1`, `A[i+i]` is one element past the end of the array.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You're also moving the smallest element up in the list.  There's no need to modify the list as you're already keeping track of the min.

Rather than checking adjacent elements, you should just compare the current element against the min.  You also don't need to move elements around, and you don't need to add a special case for an array of 1:

```
int findMin(int A[], int N)
{
    int min;
    int i;

    min = A[0];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < min)
        {
            min = A[i];
        }
    }

    return freq(min,A,N);
}
```

You also don't need to loop through the list twice, as you can count the number of times you see the min as you go through the list.